# Sending image to nodeJs server using fetch api

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I am trying to send an image via fetch API to Nodejs server. The client-side code is below

```
uploadByFile(file) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", file);

    return fetch('/editorJS/uploads', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        return json;
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

But on the server-side, I am getting buffer instead of file. How can I retrieve file there? Below is code

```
router.post('/editorJS/uploads',  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.files);
    console.log(req.files);
}
```

And the output is

```
<Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 57 65 62 4b 69 74 46 6f 72 6d 42 6f 75 6e 64 61 72 79 31 76 56 59 4d 59 4f 73 59 6a 42 67 76 5a 4b 50 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d ... 10336 more bytes>
undefined
undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multer package for get file in nodejs, i am put a code below you.

```
const multer = require('multer');

const localstorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req: any, file: any, cb: any) {
        cb(null, '');
    },

    // By default, multer removes file extensions so let's add them back
    filename: function (req: any, file: any, cb: any) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
  });

  router.post('/editorJS/uploads',  multer({ storage: localstorage }).single('file')  
  (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body);

  }
```

Comment: Please follow below link  
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/file-upload-with-multer-in-node--cms-32088

Comment: I belied you have not add this line also 

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

Comment: I think the problem is because of not using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. But I can't do this because `file` comes from a library `editorJS`

Answer (score 0):

With this buffer you can create your image and store it on folder in your server.

```
var fs = require('fs');

try{  
   fs.createWriteStream(path_folder_to_store_image).write(your_buffer);
   console.log('image upload');
}catch(error){
   console.log(error)
}
```